# How to cancel Blazor component disposing?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, idisposable

With the `IDisposable` interface one can use the `Dispose()`-Method to unsubscribe from events or stop background tasks properly. But what if I have a form and check if user updates inputs and navigates back to another page. The form state gets lost. For this I want to cancel the disposing and want to show a message. Is there a way how to stop component disposing?

Comment: When Disposing is called you Form is already destroyed. You need to tackle the navigating-away.

Comment: By change I'm currently putting together a Github Repo that shows how to deal with Edit State in Blazor Forms.  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.EditForms and a demo site on Azure - https://blazor-editforms.azurewebsites.net/.  The code is in a reasonable state, but the readme is in draft.  Everything is a bit un-polished at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a ScopedService to keep the FormState in memory. Or use the LocalStorage to keep it.